# date_trunc interval in PostgreSQL 15 minutes

Tags: c#, postgresql, date, select, group-by

```
const string query = "SELECT worker, date_trunc('hour', created) AS created, AVG(hashrate) AS hashrate, " + "AVG(sharespersecond) AS sharespersecond FROM minerstats " +
"WHERE poolid = @poolId AND miner = @miner AND created >= @start AND created <= @end " +
"GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', created), worker " +
"ORDER BY created, worker;";
```

This query displays the time periods of hours.
how to make 15 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
date_trunc('hour', created) 
    + extract(minute from created)::int / 15 * interval '15' minute
```

Comment: "GROUP BY date_trunc  
also?

Comment: @Bravo: yes you need to repeat the expression in the `group by` clause. Or simpler, use the column number: `group by 1` (if the expression is the first column in the `select` clause).